# How can I import all emails from one gmail account to another with all the original labels?

Tags: email, gmail, label

I have 2 gmail accounts: the first one is the one I'm currently using - it is a mail.huji.ac.il account (my University email), under gmail domain.

I have recently opened a standard gmail account, and I want to import all the old gmail account's mails to the new one.

The problem is that I have a lot of labels in the old account, and I want to keep them also in the new one.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't support it. If most of your labels are applied by filters, you can follow the steps below to trigger the process again.

Suppose import account A to B.

1. Enable A to forward all mails by POP: Settings, Forwarding and POP/IMAP, POP Download,Enable POP for all mail.
2. Export all filters of A as a file: Settings, Filters, Select:All, export.
3. Import the backup file of filters to B:  Settings, Filters, Import filters.
4. Enable B to receive mails from A by POP: Settings, Accounts,Check mail from other accounts, Add a POP3 mail account you own(Add POP info of account A).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the Gmail API: retrieve the emails from one account and insert them into the other account.  There appears to be a command-line tool that will do this for you, called [Got Your Back](https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back/wiki).  The commands would be something like:

```
gyb --email youremail@mail.huji.ac.il --local-folder /home/you/gmail-backup
gyb --email yournewemail@gmail.com --action restore --local-folder /home/you/gmail-backup
```